# how to make responsive li elements inside a ul in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, vertical-alignment

So I am doing a navigation menu in CSS, but I can't seem to get it correctly. 
I have 4 `li` elements inside a `ul`. I want the space between these elements to resize responsively, depending on the size of the window.

I thought about using the `margin-right` property with like a `10%` value, so the elements would spread apart more if the window is bigger. Long story short this method doesn't work and I wanted to see if anyone knows how I can make it work. I'll leave the important code beneath.

[image: How I want it to look]

[image: How it currently looks]

```css
#links li{
    margin-right: 10%;
}

#navbar li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.container-nav{
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
<div class="container-nav">
    <ul id="links">
      <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Servicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Hi Inigo. Have you thought of using Bootstrap to do this? It has all the elements and CSS you need in order to make a responsive menu!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the style for links to be

`#links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}`

This code is setting the Links ul to be a flex container and spacing the elements evenly

https://codepen.io/adamjamesturner/pen/MWYNxrx

EDIT:

The issue with your code is you need to set the `ul` to be a flex-container which then, by default, has a `flex-direction: row` and so gives the behaviour you desire.